# How to convert PASCAL VOC to YOLO

Tags: training-data, yolo, coco, voc

I was trying to develop some way to convert annotations between formats, and it's quit hard to find information but here I have :

**This one is PASCAL VOC**

```xml
<width>800</width>
<height>450</height>
<depth>3</depth>
<bndbox>
    <xmin>474</xmin>
    <ymin>2</ymin>
    <xmax>726</xmax> <!-- shape_width = 252  -->
    <ymax>449</ymax> <!-- shape_height = 447 -->
</bndbox>
```

convert to **YOLO darknet**

```
2 0.750000 0.501111 0.315000 0.993333
```

note initial `2` it's a category

Comment: This script helped me. You will have to change the ```dirs``` and the ```classes``` arguments to fit your training/test images and classification labels (respectively). https://gist.github.com/Amir22010/a99f18ca19112bc7db0872a36a03a1ec

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My classmates and I have created a python package called PyLabel to help others with this task and other labelling tasks.

This would be the basic code to convert from voc to coco:

```
!pip install pylabel
from pylabel import importer
dataset = importer.ImportVOC(path=PATH_TO_ANNOTATIONS)
dataset.export.ExportToYoloV5()
```

You can find sample notebooks and the source code here https://github.com/pylabel-project/pylabel

Answer (score 3):

using some math: (also can be useful to COCO)

```
categ_index [(xmin + xmax) / 2 / image_width] [(ymin + ymax) / 2 / image_height] [(xmax - xmin) / image_width] [(ymax  - ymin) / image_height]
```

in js code

```js
const categ_index = 2;

const { width: image_width, height: image_height } = {
  width: 800,
  height: 450,
};

const { xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax } = {
  xmin: 474,
  ymin: 2,
  xmax: 727,
  ymax: 449,
};

const x_coord = (xmin + xmax) / 2 / image_width;

const y_coord = (ymin + ymax) / 2 / image_height;

const shape_width = (xmax - xmin) / image_width;

const shape_height = (ymax - ymin) / image_height;

console.log(`${categ_index} ${x_coord.toFixed(7)} ${y_coord.toFixed(7)} ${shape_width.toFixed(7)} ${shape_height.toFixed(7)}`);

// output
// 2 0.7506250 0.5011111 0.3162500 0.9933333
```

Answer (score 1):

And another one tool:

```
pip install pascal-voc
```

```
from pascal import annotation_from_xml

# read xml file
ann = annotation_from_xml(ann_file)

label_map = {"car": 1, "dog": 0, "person": 2, "train": 3}
# get ann str
yolo_ann = ann.to_yolo(label_map)
# save yolo format file
with open("yolo_ann.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(yolo_ann)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following snippet to convert Pascal_VOC to YOLO. Yolo uses normalized coordinates so it is important to have the height and width of your image. Otherwise you can't calculate it.

Here is my snippet:

```
# Convert Pascal_Voc bb to Yolo
def pascal_voc_to_yolo(x1, y1, x2, y2, image_w, image_h):
    return [((x2 + x1)/(2*image_w)), ((y2 + y1)/(2*image_h)), (x2 - x1)/image_w, (y2 - y1)/image_h]
```

I wrote an article about object detection format and how to convert them. You can check my blog post on Medium: https://christianbernecker.medium.com/convert-bounding-boxes-from-coco-to-pascal-voc-to-yolo-and-back-660dc6178742

Have fun!